# Remove first and last <br /> from string

Tags: javascript, html, dom, replace

I have this html code :

```
<p id="demo">Visit <br /> stackoverflow <br /> or jsfiddle <br /></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

```
function myFunction()
{
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace("<br />","");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=res;
}
```

I want to remove  first and last `<br />` from it not all of them.
this is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3W83m/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution to the general problem you ask:

```
var arr = str.split(/<br\s*\/?>/);
var res = arr[0]+arr.slice(1,-1).join('<br>')+arr.slice(-1);
```

This answer doesn't require the first and last child to be `<br>`.

If you just want to remove `<br>` at the ends, then it's easy :

```
var res = str.replace(/^\s*<br\s*\/?>|<br\s*\/?>\s*$/g,'');
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/8YJjx/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way, if you are sure that first and last element child are `br`: Other wise you can loop through to test for the first and last br and remove them.

```
function myFunction() {
    var elem= document.getElementById("demo");
    elem.removeChild(elem.firstElementChild);
    elem.removeChild(elem.lastElementChild);
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G2d7f/)**

To ensure it removes only fist and last brs and not any other element if first/last one is not a BR, you can add a simple check for safety.

```
function myFunction() {
    var elem= document.getElementById("demo"), 
        fChild = elem.firstElementChild, 
        lChild =elem.lastElementChild;

if(fChild.tagName === "BR")
    elem.removeChild(fChild);
if(lChild.tagName === "BR")
    elem.removeChild(lChild);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

first `<br/>`:

```
if (myString.indexOf('<br/>') > 0) {
  myString = myString.slice(myString.indexOf('<br/>')+5, myString.length);
}
```

last `<br/>`:

```
if (myString.lastIndexOf('<br/>') == myString.length - 5) {
  myString = myString.slice(0, -4);
}
```